# MySQL: Merge rows and returning default values

Tags: mysql, merge, coalesce, ifnull

Imagine the following table:

```
id | variant | name
-----------------------
1  | 1       | a
1  | 2       | b
1  | 3       | c
2  | 1       | d
2  | 2       | e
2  | 3       | NULL
3  | 1       | g
```

Which SQL statement do I need to run to get this:

- For a given id and a given variant get the name of this combination.
- But if the name is NULL get the name of the row with the given id but with variant 1 (the name of variant 1 is never NULL).
- If there is no row with the given variant, again, use the row where variant is 1 with the same id.
- Variant 1 is never requested directly.

This is like a fall back mechanism. Or you could consider it as overriding values of rows with variant = 1.

Examples:

- id = 1, variant = 2: b
- id = 1, variant = 3: c
- id = 2, variant = 3: d
- id = 3, variant = 5: g

Is this possible with SQL? And is it performing well if the mechanism is applied on many more fields?

Thanks!

Update:

Please note that I would like to have this mechanism **not only for the name field**. There should be further columns which should have the same behaviour - but each column should be treated on its own.

Comment: I think you need to add a multi column example to get a good answer on the performance bit. If you mean that each column should be treated on its own as in taken from variant x with a fallback to variant 1 if the value is null for the column my answer stands with just additional COALESCE, but that may be a bad assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need using a `LEFT JOIN` to get the optional value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.Name,a.Name)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON a.id=b.id AND b.variant=@y
WHERE a.id=@x AND a.variant=1
```

[An SQLFiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/545ba/6).

Performance wise, it would depend on how you need to apply the query to get multiple fields. If you can solve your column choice using `COALESCE` from the existing join, I can't see a big problem, but if you end up with multiple self joins to solve it, you may have a problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution! I tried it already with COALESCE but have got more than a single row. But you solution is right. Also with further columns. Thank you very much for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

As always, performance will depend on your data structure, how many rows you have, and what indexes you have created. I would recommend a query like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=@1 AND ((variant=@2 AND name IS NOT NULL) OR variant=1) ORDER BY variant DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work with more data columns. Joachims solution seems to be perfect. But thank you for you help.

Comment: It most certainly can work with more data columns if you do it correctly. It does not work with more than one record at a time though. Glad you got what you needed.